# Fibers of a proper birational morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Liu's book on Algebraic Geometry, and I got stuck on a proof.
The theorem he proves is (4.4.3):
Let Y be a normal locally Noetherian scheme, let X be an integral scheme and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a proper birational morphism. Then the following properties are true:
a) $\mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism.
b) There exists an open subset V of Y such that
$f^{-1}(V) \rightarrow V$ is an isomorphism and $X_y$ has no isolated points if $y \not \in V$. Moreover, the complement of V has codimension greater than or equal to 2.

I am following the first part of his proof, but the second part is to me more unclear. He writes:
Let $y \in Y$ have codimension 1 such that $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ is a DVR. Let $x \in X_y$; then $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$. Then, since any two maps from a reduced scheme to a separated scheme agreeing on a dense open subset are equal, $X_y = \{ x \}$.

I can't see how the reduced to separated theorem gives that the fiber is one point. Any help woulf
be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1, x_2\in X_y$. Consider the canonical morphisms $f_1: \mathrm{Spec}\ O_{Y,y}=\mathrm{Spec}\ O_{X,x_1}\to X$, $f_2: \mathrm{Spec}\ O_{Y,y}=\mathrm{Spec}\ O_{X,x_2}\to X$. They concide on the generic point, so they are equal by the property you alluded to. Hence $x_1=f_1(s)=f_2(s)=x_2$ where $s$ is the closed point of $\mathrm{Spec}\ O_{Y,y}$.